# JCombobox always created Private and not public

Tags: java, swing, ide, jcombobox

Just a small question, i am having a problem when creating a JCombobox in design view in netbeans and linking it to another class which calls data from the database,

JComboBox is always created as a private method therefore it's variable is not being seen in the other class so that it will get the data from the database.

Just a small question, is there a way i can create a JCombobox by simply coding it and then editing it's position in design view? it seems that when i code it, it is not displayed so i can edit it's position.

Please if i did not explain it clearly tell me so that i can show you a sample of the code.
But for now it's just a basic question i don't think i need to display the code.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Just make it public in the code.

Comment: i can't, i just drag and drop the Jcombobox to the position i want, then when i double click it create " private void comboboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)", and it cannot be edited to public

Comment: Non netbean users cannot help you without seeing your unwanted private method, please show us the code

Comment: @Sudhanshu Code by Netbeans cannot be altered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid making fields and UI components visible to other parts of the application that should not be able modify them.  These opens up your application to the possibility of modifications out side of the expected flow.

Instead, provide the means to either allow other parts of your application to supply the data you need to it or a use a listener style interface (observer pattern) to know when the data has changed/loaded and update the combobox from within the class itself

Comment: @ralph: See [*Controlling Access to Members of a Class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a public getter:

```
public JComboBox getComboBox() {
    return comboBox1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can provide public access to your JComboBox with Netbeans 7.3. Follow the steps 1, 2 and 3. Remember: anything is possible with Netbeans! It is the best IDE there is! (I do not work for Oracle. :-) )

Still it is not recommended to make it public. It is better to use an accessor like `public JComboBox getMyCombo()` instead, and keep the JComboBox private, like everybody else suggested here. The reason for this, is that you make your class easier to modify. Another class, that uses it, does not need to know the actual name of your variable, only its public methods.

You could also avoid getting the entire JComboBox component, but only the selected item or index instead, you can arrange accessors (getters) for these in the class where your JComboBox is declared, 
depending on what you are doing.

[image]